# React Redux reading data from reducer in table

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am very new to react-redux, I am trying to read hard-coded initial data in the table, I tried a lot, yet, I failed to achieve this. I am so exhausted now with this easiest thing.

this is my `postreducer.js` file

```
const initialState = [{name: 'jhon', age: '23', email: 'a@a'}, {name: 'doe', age: '24', email: 'b@a'}];

const postReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case 'ADD_POST':
        return null
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
  export default postReducer;
```

You may notice, there is initial-state, I am trying to display these in the table.

```
import React, {Fragment} from "react"
import { connect } from 'react-redux'


class Table extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            employees: this.props.employees
        };

    }


    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Age</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.props.employees.map((item, index) => (
                    <tr key={index}>
                        <td>{item.name}</td>
                        <td>{item.age}</td>
                        <td>{item.email}</td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
                </tbody>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { employees } = state
    return { employees: employees }
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Table)
```

this is my `App.js` file:

```
import React from "react"
import Table from "./table"

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>              
            <table>
                <Table />
            </table>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

and this is my `index.js` file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./components/App";

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import { createStore } from 'redux'
import postReducer from '../src/redux/reducers/postReducer'

const store = createStore(postReducer)


ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Can anyone help me to display `initialstate` data in a table with redux?

Comment: Can you share your rootReducer code as well?

Comment: I dont have rootreducer

Comment: I hope you notice i create store with postReducer

Comment: reducer created with root reducer, can you confirm that you used combineReducers in a root reducer

Comment: const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    employees: postReducer
});

rootReducer should look like this

Comment: From your `index.js`: `import rootReducer from '../src/redux/reducers/rootReducer'`

Comment: No, I didnt use combinereducer

Comment: Sorry, it is postreducer

Comment: I have edited it now, please check this now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { employees } = state
    return { employees: employees }
  }
```

You are pulling `employees` from the state, however you don't have employees variable in your `initial state`. This is your first mistake. So change your `initial state` with this:

```
const initialState = {
      employees: [{name: 'jhon', age: '23', email: 'a@a'}, {name: 'doe', age: '24', email: 'b@a'}] 
};
```

---

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            employees: this.props.employees
        };
    }
```

Why are you setting your `props` to the `state`. Do not do this. Use `this.props.employees`  to access the data.

Comment: Thanks, You made my day